# jquery not updating DOM immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have looked through a few other questions, and tried a few options, but still a bit of a loss.

EDIT - JUST TO SHOW THE ACTUAL AJAX CALL BEING MADE..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AJAXget/getPostcodeCheck.ashx',
    data: 'postcode=' + postcode,
    async: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: postcodeCallback,
    error: function () {
        alert('Sorry, there was an issue contacting the server.. please retry.');
        return;
    }
});
```

I have the following jQuery AJAX bind function, where I want to show something is loading for instance..

```
$('#' + btnID).bind('ajaxStart', function () {
    $('#' + btnID).append('<div>loading</div>');
});
```

This is just a basic example.. I did use an addClass function to the element (#btnID is a div), but again nothing seemed to happen directly.

I have put an alert statement in the function to test that the ajaxStart is being triggered, and it does seem to be.. so I am guessing my lack of DOM understanding and/or jQuery is at fault!  i.e. why any DOM update/injection is not being shown immediately?

Any pointers/ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).append('<div>loading</div>');` ?

Comment: Actually stupidly no!  I think I had that originally.. but with chopping and changing.. will try thanks!

Comment: Actually tried $(this) too.. same issue  JUST AS AN EXTRA.. IT DOES ADD TO THE DOM/REFRESH ONCE THE AJAXSTOP COMPLETES.. I.E. ANY OUTSTANDING FUNCTIONS COMPLETE FIRST?

Comment: p.s: used IE 8, Firefox 3+, Chrome etc.. all seem to have the same effect?

Comment: Are your ajax calls synchronous (`async: false`)? *Show more code.*

Comment: Thanks Matt Ball - I have added the original AJAX calling code - actually async is false

Comment: Actually tried with async true and false.. same issue

Comment: As per the [`.ajaxStart()` api docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/): `"Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests.` **`If none are in progress,`** `jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time."` So, either you have outstanding Ajax requests in progress (so the event doesn't fire), or you're binding the `ajaxStart` handler too late - say, after the actual Ajax call. Could you post a **complete** example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coding your ajaxStart method like this:

```
$('#' + btnID).ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).append('<div>loading</div>');
});
```

Also, see what happens when you simplify your jQuery Ajax call to this:

```
$.get('AJAXget/getPostcodeCheck.ashx', { postcode: postcode }, function(data) {
  //$('#yourResultElement').html(data);
  console.info(data);
});
```

If you're using Firebug (you're using Firebug, right?), click the Console tab and see what's returned.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up cutting back to real basics and just having a simple div update when clicked.. thanks!  p.s: using chrome with their dev tools.. similar to firebug of course!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is called after user clicks a button. In that case, why you don't do the following:

1. Before the Ajax-call you do:  $('#' + btnID).append('loading');
2. On Success or Error, you do:  $('#' + btnID).remove();

I'm sure that approach will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have now since added a very simple popup notification triggered by the onclick event.